# How do I display only the keys of a dataframe as the xticks of a plot, in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with keys, formed from the concatenation of several dataFrames and I want to make a plot that has the `key` elements alone as the `xtickslabel`, but the default **index** numbering shows up alongside the keys, as the xtickslabel. The xticklabels are now tuples **(key, index)** instead of `key`. I want to get rid of the default **index** values. A plot of the sample code below with the plot statement, produces `(4D, 0), (5D, 0), (6D, 0), and (7D, 0)` as the the xticklabels, However, I want just `4D, 5D, 6D, 7D` as the xticklabels.

```py
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.DataFrame([2, 4, 6, 8], columns = ['A'])
dfB = pd.DataFrame([4, 6, 8, 10], columns = ['B'])
dfC = pd.DataFrame([6, 8, 10, 12], columns = ['C']) 

alldata = pd.concat([dfA, dfB, dfC], keys = ['4D', '5D', '6D', '7D'])

alldata.plot.bar(title = 'Data', ylabel = 'y', xlabel = 'x')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the for statement, save the first item from each index into the list and pass it over to the parameter in `set_xticklabels`.

```py
# Get the first value of each tuple.
indexList = [item[0] for item in alldata.index]
```

indexList:

```
['4D', '4D', '4D', '4D', '5D', '5D', '5D', '5D', '6D', '6D', '6D', '6D']
```

So the full source is..

```
import pandas as pd

dfA = pd.DataFrame([2, 4, 6, 8], columns = ['A'])
dfB = pd.DataFrame([4, 6, 8, 10], columns = ['B'])
dfC = pd.DataFrame([6, 8, 10, 12], columns = ['C']) 

alldata = pd.concat([dfA, dfB, dfC], keys = ['4D', '5D', '6D', '7D'])

# Get the first value of each tuple.
indexList = [item[0] for item in alldata.index]

ax = alldata.plot.bar(title = 'Data', ylabel = 'y', xlabel = 'x')

# Set xticklabels
ax.set_xticklabels(indexList);
```

Output:
[image]

---

#### EDIT

1. Create a DataFrame that indexes '4D', '5D', '6D', and '7D'.

```py
index = ['4D', '5D', '6D', '7D']

dfA = pd.DataFrame([2, 4, 6, 8], columns=['A'], index=index)
dfB = pd.DataFrame([4, 6, 8, 10], columns=['B'], index=index)
dfC = pd.DataFrame([6, 8, 10, 12], columns=['C'], index=index)
```

2. Set to `axis=1`, then Dataframes will be merged by sideways.

```py
alldata = pd.concat([dfA, dfB, dfC], axis=1)
```

3. Plotting (same with your code)

```py
alldata.plot.bar(title = 'Data', ylabel = 'y', xlabel = 'x')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: sorry I did not include that I wanted to get a grouped bar plot of corresponding elements in all three dataframe that has been concatenated. So it will be (2,4,6) under 4D, (4,6,8) under 5D, (6,8,10) for 6D and 8,10,12) for 7D. That's the reason I added the keys in the first place. So that I could just plot it and the keys show up as the ticklabels at once. I've searched for a means of deleting the default index but it's proving difficult.

Comment: @Fonnie Then how about indexing '4D', '5D', '6D', and '7D' when creating three Dataframes at first? I edited my post. And I don't know how much it fits with the results you want, but I think it's simpler than dealing with a tuple key.

Comment: Thanks a whole lot @elena.kim. It works like magic.

Comment: @Fonnie If my answer was helpful, please accept my answer :)

Comment: So sorry about that. I'm very grateful for your input.